# Nested data structure in migration from mongoDB to clickhouse

Tags: mongodb, clickhouse, nested-datalist

In my mongoDB, there are nested data structures with three different levels, as the pictures are shown . Since mongo engine in clickhouse doesn't support such structures, I try to define these fields as String when creating table using mongoDB engine, but failed to retrieve data. Should I predefine new tables(normalise each nested structure) and then insert values from mongo to CH? Do you have alternatives？

[image: 1st nested structure]

[image: 2nd nested structure]

[image: 3rd nested structure]

Answer (score 0):

From https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/mongodb/

> MongoDB Engine supports only non-nested data types.

You can use [Map](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/map/) data type if you can flatten the schema of the MongoDB collection.

Alternatively, you can save the whole document (JSON) as `String` and work on it with [JSON functions](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/).